# How can I use Hammer for Mac to build out markdown files

Tags: haml, markdown, hammerformac

If I have, say, 50 markdown files, I don't want to create a HAML template for each of one them. Is there a way to have Hammer for Mac use the markdown pages and a single HAML template to build out HTML pages for each?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a [static site generator](https://www.staticgen.com/) ([more here](https://staticsitegenerators.net/)).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but Hammer for Mac is a static site generator. I need to know how to build out multiple markdown files with it.